# Emacs How to redefine Shift-R for expected use

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings

I've checked my elisp files to make sure that I do not have any bindings that contain Shift+R (and I have not found any). I expect SHIFT+R to print an uppercase character, but instead I get *R R undefined* inside of the Emacs command line. This is only in C/C++ major modes.

Any suggestions?

**Update**: Describing the key shows that it is undefined. How would I define it for the normal, expected use (capitalizing the letter R)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by the 'expected use' you mean to insert the 'R' character. For this, you'd need to bind the key to 'self-insert-command':

```
M-x global-set-key R self-insert-command
```

Or, in your .emacs or .emacs.d/init.el file:

```
(global-set-key "R" 'self-insert-command)
```

Of course, this should be the default....

Comment: No, when I press Shift+R, "R" appears as if I am going to type a command (similar to M-x).

Comment: The problem was actually fixed by this answer, but the root of the problem came from the X Window software I was using. Apparently it was binding the left ALT key to something other than ALT. After a little searching it seems this has to do with legacy support for older keyboards.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting a little deja-vu here and if memory serves the behavior I encountered some years ago was that (on Windows) certain accessibility settings unset or changed the keycode for the right shift key.  Sorry I cannot be more specific but maybe this will stimulate someone else to come up with the real answer.  A test you can make: does the behavior work with both shift keys or just one?  If the answer is just one shows the bad behavior, is that bad behavior shown with all keys?

Comment: Just the left shift key, but this is through X forwarding (and sticky keys are off).

Answer (score 1):

Try C-h k (describe-key), then press Shift-R. describe-key will then tell you what is bound to that key. At least that will give you a hint as to whether or not there is an active binding. If there's a binding, perhaps it will give you a hint of something else to search for in your startup files.

Comment: It says that the key is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you're having the same problem I had.  Typing Re... in any html buffer would try to execute an R- command, when every single R-* command was undefined.  Turned out that I had a typo in my .emacs file.  I had a global-key-map set to `(kbd "REF")` instead of `(kbd "RET")`, and fixing it made the problem immediately vanish.  So I'd recommend checking for anything similar in your .emacs file.